# Input one fixed cluster centroid, find N others (python)

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I have a table of shipment destinations in lat, long. I have one fixed origination point (also lat, long). I would like to find other optimal origin locations using clustering. In other words, I want to assign one cluster centroid (keep it fixed) and find 1, 2, 3 . . . N other cluster centroids. Is this possible with the scikit learn cluster module?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than recycling clustering for this, treat it as a regular **optimization problem**. You don't want to "discover structure", but optimize cost.

Beware that earth is not flat, and Euclidean distance (i.e. k-means) is a bad idea. 1 degree north is only at the equator approximately the same distance to 1 degree east. If your data is e.g. in New York, you have a non-neglibile distortion, and your solution will not even be a local optimum.

If you absolutely insist on abusing kmeans, it's easy to do.

Choose n-1 centers at random and the predefined one.
Then run 1 iteration of k-means only. Then **replace that center with the desired center again**. Repeat with the next iteration.

Comment: Yes this will obviously not work in every scenario, nor is it the only piece of the analysis. I'm simply wondering if it's possible to do with scikit learn for exploratory purposes. I could not find in the documentation or in examples where I could specify one cluster centroid and find additional others.